# Code Generation in TDS

Tags: sitecore, code-generation, tds

I am new in TDS and i'm a bit lost in 'Code Generation' property. I can't fully understand the process going on in here and don't really know what to do next. I've followed the instructions here --> ' http://jignesh-patel.com/sitecore-automate-code-generation-using-tds-t4-text-template/ ' to enable code generation. I created those header and template files and clicked 'Regenerate code for all items' which generated a cs file that contains 2963 lines of code. I don't know if i'm doing the right thing. Please help me understand.

Comment: Hi Marife, it may be easier to answer your question if it was more specific. Is the code you generated the code you wanted to use? What are you trying to do with code generation? If you can explain what you are attempting to do with the generated code somebody might be able to guide you as to how to accomplish that.

Comment: Hi Thanks for noticing. I was trying to do serialization, so the other users of TDS can synchronize database changes  to their local.

Comment: TDS synchronization and serialization is unrelated to code generation. You would use code generation more for creating code based on your structures. For example, you might want a class that has properties that match your fields on your templates.

I would recommend changing your question to ask about the serialization and how to sync items into your TDS project.

Comment: Will you please guide me on how to sync and serialize items in TDS ?

Comment: You probably want to start with this Help guide: https://www.hhogdev.com/help/tds.

Then post a Q&A here on StackExchange for a specific issue once you get stuck.

Alternatively, you can join the Forums or Slack to get more realtime help. I have some links here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/developer-getting-started-

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!